# What is the maximum amount of pending edits allowed?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I was editing grammar on a number of old posts when suddenly the edit button began to be grayed out. When I hover over the edit button it gives the message "Account has the maximum amount of pending edit suggestions." I have never gotten this message before... so my question is, What is the maximum number of pending edits allowed?

Comment: Just to save you a click: 5 (graduated site) or 20 (beta site)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Is that per hour or per day?

Comment: No time period - an edit is pending until it is approved or rejected, so once you hit the limit you're done editing until one or more of your edits is reviewed.

Comment: That's just at a time. Once one of your suggested edits is out of the queue, you should be able to submit a new one. (Provided you aren't temp banned from suggesting edits.)

Comment: Noice, it didn't even take a whole day.